# Diff in commit toolbar IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, diff, commit

I have commit toolbar (`⌘+0` for mac) with a list of changed files and i want to see the diff (`⌘D`). Currently diff is displayed in editor tab or i can switch it to show in a separate window, no more choice.

But I want to show it next to changelist at the bottom instead of text area with Commit Message and commit button. I know it's possible, but cannot find it anywhere. How can I put it there?

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that Local Changes have been moved to a separate Commit tool window. To return it back you can change this in your
Settings -> Version Control -> Commit  -> Use non-modal commit interface.

This is should be on Git toolbar (`⌘+9`), not Commit toolbar (`⌘+0`)

See more on corresponding thread at intellij-support.jetbrains [Version control local changes tab missing in 2020.1](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008229959-Version-control-local-changes-tab-missing-in-2020-1)